# Postman-javascript: How to set next request to a call in a different folder in loaded collection

Tags: javascript, postman

In the following code, "LoopTillHealthy" is set as the next request.

```
if (!(someValue && allGreen)) {
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("HEALTH_ITER", curIt+1);
    if (parseInt(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("HEALTH_ITER"))<=maxIt) {
        postman.setNextRequest("LoopTillHealthy");
    }
} else {
    tests["HEALTH CHECK AFTER "+postman.getEnvironmentVariable("HEALTH_ITER")+" calls"] = allGreen;
}
```

Now I may have multiple folders within the same collection each containing its own implementation of "LoopTillHealthy". 
How is it possible in postman to call from different folders using "postman.setNextRequest".

Is there something similar to:

```
postman.setNextRequest(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("TARGET_FOLDER")+"\LoopTillHealthy");
```

or,

```
postman.setNextRequest(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("TARGET_COLLECTION")+"\"+postman.getEnvironmentVariable("TARGET_FOLDER")+"\LoopTillHealthy");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported at the moment. 
There are several feature requests in the official postman support Github:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2851
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2819